# Get better quality from SoundCloud's Waveform.js lib

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, soundcloud, waveform

Currently I'm using Waveform.js (http://waveformjs.org) to generate waveforms from SoundCloud tracks.

Unfortunately the generated `canvas` has a very low image quality (especially on Retina):

[image]

I would like to create Waveform very similar to the Soundcloud one:

[image]

Do you know how can I improve the quality of an image? Maybe there's a better solution for generating such waveforms?

My app is completely client-side, everything is done in the browser, so perfect scenario for me will be:

1. Send `waveform_url` to the library which can generate `canvas`/`svg`/etc.
2. Or get the data from `waveform_url` by myself and feed it to the library.
3. Also it will be superb to sync HTML5 `Audio` element playing together with generated waveform.

I'll appreciate any input and suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add on to [@XGreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27903184/1397319), try inserting the following into [waveform.coffee](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/blob/bd2fc27a5975077db347b24e314096a7e053ac9a/views/waveform.coffee#L20) after line 19:

```
# High DPI Canvas
devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1
backingStoreRatio = @context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio || @context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio || @context.msBackingStorePixelRatio || @context.oBackingStorePixelRatio || @context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1
@ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio
if devicePixelRatio isnt backingStoreRatio
  @canvas.width  = @ratio * @width
  @canvas.height = @ratio * @height
  @canvas.style.width  = "#{@width}px"
  @canvas.style.height = "#{@height}px"
  @context.scale @ratio, @ratio
```

I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/pull/22) to merge this change.

Comment: @Kosmetika excellent. Can you mark the answer as correct and possibly +1 my [pull request](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/pull/22) so other people don't have this issue in the future? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the code of this library. But in general principle

```
//if canvas context is:
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//then the device ratio can be calculated using:
var     devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
        backingStoreRatio = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                            context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                            context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                            context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
                            context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1,

        ratio = devicePixelRatio / backingStoreRatio;

//now you can scale your canvas and for retina display I think it will be 2 and 2

context.scale(ratio, ratio)
```

Read the library code and see where you can add this ratio support. Hope this helps.

[Here is also a reference/sample](http://blog.tripleaxis.com/optimising-html5-canvas-elements-for-retina-screens/)

Comment: I have access to `context` in the library but `scale`ing didn't help. Here is how the canvas looks after applying your changes - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100463011/waveform-js2.png