# CoffeeScript Compiling

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, waveform

I want to use customised [waveformjs](http://www.waveformjs.org/). I found [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903004/get-better-quality-from-soundclouds-waveform-js-lib), however, I don't know how to compile/install the waveform to get started. I cloned it from [GitHub](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs) and made the changes however, I couldn't figure out how to convert it to .js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile coffeescript locally, you'll have to set up a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) environment, use `npm` to install the `coffee-script` package, and compile it with that.

If you just need to convert it one time and have no intention of using coffeescript regularly, it's probably faster to use an online tool to convert it for you. If that's the case, I recommend [js2.coffee](http://js2.coffee) or [coffeescript.org's try page](http://coffeescript.org/#try:).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: http://coffeescript.org/#usage

You need to have node.js installed, which you can use to install coffeescript and compile it from the REPL.